# When using Mongoose query, how do I save the query and use it as a parameter when rendering an EJS page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, mongoose, ejs

I am trying to build an admin dashboard and part of this admin dashboard, I'd like to present mongoose data such as users and recent tutoring sessions done. I am having trouble saving this data and assigning it to EJS parameters when rendering the page.

```
// Admin Dashboard

  // Find students
  function getUsers() {
  User.find({tutor:false}, function(err, foundItems) {
    return foundItems
  })}
  // Find sessions
  function getSessions() {
  Session.find({}, function(err, foundItems) {
    return foundItems;
  })}

app.get('/admin', function(req, res){
    res.render("pages/admin", {
      users: getUsers(),
      sessions: getSessions()
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

First observation:

`User.find()` is an asynchronous function, i.e, the main flow of the program will not wait for it to execute, hence `undefined` will be passed to the JS object. To avoid this, you must return a promise, or use async await. Here's an example:

```
async function getUsers() {
  const foundItems = await User.find({tutor:false})
  return foundItems;
}
  // Find sessions
  async function getSessions() {
  const foundItems = await Session.find({});
  return foundItems;
}

app.get('/admin', async function(req, res){
    res.render("pages/admin", {
      users: await getUsers(),
      sessions: await getSessions()
    })
  });
```

This is easier to read. You can make it shorter:

```
async function getUsers() {
  return User.find({tutor:false});
}
  // Find sessions
  async function getSessions() {
  return Session.find({});
}

app.get('/admin', async function(req, res){
    res.render("pages/admin", {
      users: await getUsers(),
      sessions: await getSessions()
    })
  });
```

Since you're directly returning foundItems (without using it anywhere), you need not await it, you can directly return the promise for the callback to await.